# arcpy.Intersect_analysis() returns empty result, but Intersect tool in ArcMap is succesful

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, intersection, arctoolbox

I've got two large feature classes that I'm trying to perform an intersect on. Using the following python code, I get an empty output feature class:

```
arcpy.Intersect_analysis(["Schools","Zips"], "Intersect_output","ALL")
```

Yet when I use the Intersect_analysis tool from the arcMap toolbox with these same two feature classes, it performs the intersect as expected. I've used the above code as part of a script that intersects a whole bunch of feature class pairs, and it does fine with most of them, but not these two feature classes in particular.

Can anyone think of a reason that these feature classes in particular might fail where others succeeded? I can't post the data, unfortunately, as I am not authorized to distribute it.

UPDATES:

Some more information:
*The failure now appears to be intermittent. After running code above exactly as shown in the arcmap python interpreter, it failed. I entered the exact same code (changing only the output feature class name, and this time it generated the correct intersect. I didn't touch the data, nor did I change the code, nor did I even close the python window between runs. it seems completely random. Has anyone ever encountered this behavior before? Might this be an arcpy bug?

*Both feature classes are using the exact same coordinate system.

*I have a separate script that calls the line of code above, but I'm testing it in the arcmap python interpreter, and I has failed there as well.

Comment: Are you defining an arcpy.env.workspace for these layers?

Comment: Can you post your script?

Comment: Are their coordinate systems different? In ArcMap it is possible to apply a transformation but this cannot be done in arcpy (that I know of), if the coordinate systems are different there could be an empty intersection due to confusion over spatial reference. p.s. as Aaron asked, more script please, just in case there is a problem on another line.

Comment: A code snippet that demonstrates your problem will help a lot.  Not being able to share your data could be circumvented by creating feature classes from the confidential datasets that have rectangles in place of the data (Create Fishnet) but are similarly located and have the same coordinate systems.  Consider including the code to create these feature classes at the beginning.

Comment: For those wanting to see the full script, I've been running the single line of code as a stand-alone in the arcMap python interpreter and encountered the same problems. Please see the updated post for more info.

Comment: The next thing to look at is bad geometries, use Repair Geometry to fix them before running the script.

Comment: I think it is time to close all applications of ArcGIS for Desktop, reboot if possible, and then try to perform the same steps that are currently giving you unexpected results - starting with the simplest scenario of running it from the Python window of ArcMap.

Comment: This is something to do with default database, happened to me few times. Good fix to specify output as shapefile

Comment: I think this may be a question better posed to [Esri Support](http://support.esri.com) because it is likely to be more or less unique to your installation.  From the [Help](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "**We are not a GIS Software Support Site.** We encourage you to seek official routes for support for specific issues you may have."